# Location of Intellij Idea 2017.1 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: intellij

Long back I have installed Intellij idea. I want to completely remove it now.
I deleted /usr/local/bin/idea
I delete ~/.IntellXXX directory

I don't see any result if do 'which idea' or 'whereis idea'

However I am still able to find idea and launch it through 'search your computer'
I am wondering where is idea installed and is still getting launched.

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: How did you install `Intellij idea`? The best way to uninstall it is to reverse the install process.

Comment: @Ravexina I dont remember how I installed 1.5 years back :(

Answer (score 4):

I installed via "Ubuntu Software"

my location is `/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/current/bin`

to locate bin folder I have used:

- (needed to increase RAM)
- "Files" [CTRL + F] "idea"
- found that: `/snap/...`, `Home/...`, `/var/snap...`, `/run/user...` and more

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have enough rights to see your current idea location. Try to issue command like

```
ls your-path-from-which-idea
```

i.e.

```
which idea | ls
```

as root and you'll probably see contents of a folder above your current idea install folder.
You can remove the folder via full path then as root (via sudo).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the product completely, do the following:

- Delete the installation directory
- Delete the "config" and "system" configuration directories. These contain IntelliJ IDEA's caches, configuration and plugins.

See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 for the OS specific locations of these two directories.

That should be all you need.

Comment: the question is how to locate the installation directory, though

Answer (score 0):

**Warning:** Deleting directories is never a good idea. It can render some package managers broken or software in a extremely difficult to recover half-installed state!

Best always to first uninstall the way you installed it. And after having successfully removed it the correct way, you can start deleting any left-over configuration files.

Some likely ways to check for installations and how to remove (if the installation is ultimate edition):

#### snap

```
snap list | grep -i intellij
```

```
sudo snap remove intellij-idea-ultimate
```

#### flatpak

```
flatpak list --app | grep -i intellij
```

```
sudo flatpak uninstall com.jetbrains.IntelliJ-IDEA-Ultimate
```

#### apt

```
apt list --installed | grep -i intellij
```

```
sudo apt purge intellij-idea-ultimate
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it's that, but I was able to find the location under the shortcut I had on desktop. It was XFCE and I right-clicked on the shortcut, went to "properties" and then "launcher". Under command there was a path that looks like installation directory for me (named *idea-IC-191.7479.19*).